# Did Jon von Neumann know about Claude Shannon's work when he wrote the "First Draft of a Report on the EDVAC?"

Tags: history, digital-circuits

In the "First Draft" JvN described an adder circuit to do binary addition, which was a much faster way of doing computer addition than using decimal lookup tables as the ENIAC had done. JvN's main reference was McCulloch and Pitts' neuron model (although Eckert and Mauchly claimed it was their idea).

However, CS had described logical circuits in his 1936 master's thesis " A Symbolic Analysis of Relay and Switching Circuits," including an adder circuit. JvN and CS were colleagues at the IAS, and in any case it seems JvN would have wanted to read as groundbreaking a work as "A Symbolic Analysis." Do we know if JvN was aware of this work?